# Installing PIP on dreamhost

Tags: python, django, pip, easy-install, dreamhost

I saw a similar question with the same error messages but I'm trying to upgrade Django/Python on Dreamhost and do not have sudo privileges with this account. My problem right now is with easy_install pip - it says "please make appropriate changes to your system and try again" but I have no idea what I am supposed to do here.

[tambotie]$ easy_install pip
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/test-easy-install-21876.pth'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install virtualenv. This can install packages into a location that you have permissions and will integrate the virtual environment with the python interpreter from your system. The package can be found at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv.

I suggest you follow the route install locally (of course if you can't install it global).
From the docs

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python virtualenv.py myVE
```

Comment: Doing that claims the the file I downloaded has data.

Comment: The instructions of virtualenv http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/